# Do I have to file a tax return in the United States?

Tags: united-states, taxes, united-kingdom, income

I've moved to the United States in November 2016. I am getting widows pension from UK, do I have to file a US tax return for 2016?

Comment: what is your status in the US? have you been in the US before you moved?

Comment: You moved without getting this sort of basic advice first? Given that, I really think you should see a financial counselor to do a sanity check of your financial arrangements to make sure the (very) basics are covered.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to wait until January and [go here.](https://apps.irs.gov/app/IPAR/investigate/IPAR_1/en-US/Attribute~Who_Must_File~global~global/qs%24s2%40TLC_WhoMustFile_Development_Screens_WMFLanding_xint%24global%24global?user=guest)

Chance are if you do have to file, it will be an easy form that some sites offer for free.

Comment: I'm afraid this link is broken now